# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in line 30

Tags: php

[I really have been having problems with this code. I can't just figure how to connect my forms with my database.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJriI.png)

Comment: at line 30 to be precise

Comment: Don't post image of the code instead write the code

Comment: And your woes entirely stem from careless indentation.

Answer (score 0):

your else statement is bad I think

correct:
LIMIT 1 ";}